# How to retrieve search result data objects from view to controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, search

I am using Laravel 6 and I am developing an app used solely for searching huge tables.

I made different functions to sort via distance (geolocation, given address, or simple zone selecting), so far I did the tests with `Model::all();` and they work fine.

I added a search filter on my Model and it works.

The thing is : I want to retrieve the results in a data like $filteredResults and then, use the different functions with the same $filteredResults.

I want the user to be able to sort the search results via the different buttons/functions.

How to retrieve the search results that are Object data from the view to the Controller.

My view (*putting just 1 button for example, I won't bother you with the several buttons for distance sorting*) :

```
<!-- FILTER FORM -->    
<form method="POST" action="/events/search" class="w-50">
    @csrf
    <input name="Nom" id="Nom" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom de l'évènement" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type d'évènement" id="Type" name="Type" />
    <input name="lieu" id="lieu" type="text" placeholder="Lieu de l'évènement" class="form-control" />
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Filtrer</button>
</form>

<!-- SORTING METHODS -->
<!-- AROUND ME -->
<!-- BY ADDRESS -->
<!-- BY AREA / ZONE -->
<a class="stpierre" href="/events/St-Pierre">Saint-Pierre</a>

<!-- TABLE DISPLAYING EVENTS --> 
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead class="text-center thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Nom</th>
            <th scope="col">Thématique</th>
            <th scope="col">Lieu</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Programme</th>
            <th scope="col">Objectif</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($events as $produit)
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ $produit -> idNosEvenements}}</th>
            <td>{{ $produit -> Nom}} </td>
            <td>{{ $produit -> idThematiques }}</td>
            <td>{{ $produit -> lieu }}</td>
            <td>{{ $produit -> Type }}</td>
            <td class="text-center"> {{ $produit -> Programme }} </td>
            <td class="text-center"> {{ $produit -> Objectifs }} </td>                       
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My routes :

```
// EVENTS
Route::get('/events', 'MesEventsController@index'); // retrieve all events
Route::post('/events/a-proximite', 'MesEventsController@distGeoLoc'); // sort all events near user
Route::post('/events/search', 'MesEventsController@searchEvents'); // filter search for events
Route::get('/events/{zone}', 'MesEventsController@distZone'); // sort all events by area
Route::get('/test/geocode', 'MesEventsController@distGeocode'); // sort all events by geocoding address
```

My controller :

```
public function index() {
    $events = Nosevenement::all();
    return view('events', ['events' => $events]);
}

// SORTING METHODS WITH EVENTS:all() FOR TESTING PURPOSES
// SORTING EVENTS BY AREA / ZONE
public function distZone($zone) {
    switch($zone) {
    case "St-Pierre":
        $latitude = -21.3328174;
        $longitude = 55.4630668;
        break;
    case "St-Paul":
        $latitude = -21.0140263;
        $longitude = 55.2607508;
        break;
    default:
        $latitude = -20.8926767;
        $longitude = 55.4827193;
        break;
    }
    $query = Nosevenement::distance($latitude, $longitude);
    $asc = $query -> orderBy('distance', 'ASC') -> get();
    return view('events', ['events' => $asc], ['zone' => $zone]);
}
```

I tried to serialize() the search results and put them in a hidden input then retrieve and unserialize() them but I got an error :

```
public function distZone($zone, Request $request) {
    // dd($zone, $request);
    if(!empty($request)) {
        $query = unserialize($request);
    }
    switch ($zone) { etc }
```

> unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 19097 bytes

So I think the search results are too big. *I am maybe wondering to retrieve only the search results $id ?*

I don't think I have enough perspective on this for the moment, if you have any idea that would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work both in backend and frontend (backend is for another project).

But for the frontend, I had to do some tweaking because I encountered many issues.

In the end, I looped through all rows to calculate the distance for each event and then passed it to a data attribute in HTML.

The sorting then happens with the data attribute and from there, it appends the rows to the body.

```
$('#results tbody tr').each(function() {
    const a_lat = $(this).data('lat');
    const a_lon = $(this).data('lon');
    var a_distance = distance(a_lat, a_lon, latitude, longitude, 'K');
    $(this).attr("data-madist", a_distance);
    console.log(Math.round(a_distance) + "km entre l'évènement et " + zone);
});

const compare_rows = function (a, b) {
    return a.getAttribute('data-madist') - b.getAttribute('data-madist');
};

// Calls the comparison function and then adds the results to the body
$('#results > tbody > .sortable').sort(compare_rows).appendTo('#results tbody');
```

Thanks again for the JS samples ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is only about sorting, right? not to do a more precise filter?

If you wants to serialize your request parameters, you have to use `->all()` (export all parameters to array):

```php
// Serialize parameters to append them into hidden input
// <input type="hidden" name="s" value="{{ $s }}">
$s = serialize($request->all());

// Unserialize after
$params = unserialize($request->s);
```

If you only wants to do sorting, you can do it easily with Javascript directly in your view. It will be more efficient, and will not overload server of simple sorting tasks.

I recommand you to use jQuery on client side. You can append your coordinates as data attribute for your rows:

```html
<a class="stpierre" href="javascript:sortDistZone(-21.3328174, 55.4630668)">Saint-Pierre</a>

<table id="results" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead class="text-center thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">Nom</th>
            <th scope="col">Thématique</th>
            <th scope="col">Lieu</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Programme</th>
            <th scope="col">Objectif</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($events as $produit)
        <tr data-lat="{{ $produit->latitude }}" data-lon="{{ $produit->longitude }}">
            <th scope="row">{{ $produit -> idNosEvenements}}</th>
            <td>{{ $produit -> Nom}} </td>
            <td>{{ $produit -> idThematiques }}</td>
            <td>{{ $produit -> lieu }}</td>
            <td>{{ $produit -> Type }}</td>
            <td class="text-center"> {{ $produit -> Programme }} </td>
            <td class="text-center"> {{ $produit -> Objectifs }} </td>                       
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    return ... your distance function here ...;
}

sortDistZone(latitude, longitude) {
    // A simple compare function, used by the sort below
    const compare_rows = function (a, b) {
        const a_lat = $(a).data('lat');
        const a_lon = $(a).data('lon');
        const a_distance = distance(a_lat, a_lon, latitude, longitude);

        const b_lat = $(b).data('lat');
        const b_lon = $(b).data('lon');
        const b_distance = distance(a_lat, a_lon, latitude, longitude);

        if (a_distance>b_distance){
            return 1;
        }
        if (a_distance<b_distance){
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    };

    // the actual sort
    $('#results tr').sort(compare_rows).appendTo('#results tbody');
}
</script>
```

Bon courage !! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pierre ! 
I did try the hidden input and serialize (sorry, I forgot to update my code) but the unserialize gives me an error.
When I `dd($request -> results);` I get a very big string with all the data, but the **unserialize** gets me an error.


For the jQuery sorting, I admit I haven't thought about it. I will give it a try. Especially since 3/4 of the distance sortings I do, retrieve data via a script.

Et merci !! :)